# Does AMD Mantle API already available?

Tags: mantle

Is the AMD Mantle API already available for developers? Where can we get it? Can't wait any longer.

Links to read:

- [Mantle (API)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mantle_%28API%29)
- [AMD’s Revolutionary Mantle](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/mantle/pages/mantle.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Right now there is no official Mantle SDK available, but there is a beta driver (AMD Catalyst™ 14.1 Beta Driver for Windows). The beta driver contains a mantle64.dll and a mantleaxl64.dll library. Dependency walker unviels the following function definitions:

```
******** mantle64.dll ******** 
IcdDbgMessage 
DllMain 
grAllocMemory 
grAttachImageViewDescriptors 
grAttachMemoryViewDescriptors 
grAttachNestedDescriptors 
grAttachSamplerDescriptors 
grBeginCommandBuffer 
grBeginDescriptorSetUpdate 
grBindObjectMemory 
grClearDescriptorSetSlots 
grCmdBeginQuery 
grCmdBindDescriptorSet 
grCmdBindDynamicMemoryView 
grCmdBindIndexData 
grCmdBindPipeline 
grCmdBindStateObject 
grCmdBindTargets 
grCmdClearColorImage 
grCmdClearColorImageRaw 
grCmdClearDepthStencil 
grCmdCloneImageData 
grCmdCopyImage 
grCmdCopyImageToMemory 
grCmdCopyMemory 
grCmdCopyMemoryToImage 
grCmdDbgMarkerBegin 
grCmdDbgMarkerEnd 
grCmdDispatch 
grCmdDispatchIndirect 
grCmdDraw 
grCmdDrawIndexed 
grCmdDrawIndexedIndirect 
grCmdDrawIndirect 
grCmdEndQuery 
grCmdFillMemory 
grCmdInitAtomicCounters 
grCmdLoadAtomicCounters 
grCmdMemoryAtomic 
grCmdPrepareImages 
grCmdPrepareMemoryRegions 
grCmdResetEvent 
grCmdResetQueryPool 
grCmdResolveImage 
grCmdSaveAtomicCounters 
grCmdSetEvent 
grCmdUpdateMemory 
grCmdWriteTimestamp 
grCreateColorBlendState 
grCreateColorTargetView 
grCreateCommandBuffer 
grCreateComputePipeline 
grCreateDepthStencilState 
grCreateDepthStencilView 
grCreateDescriptorSet 
grCreateDevice 
grCreateEvent 
grCreateFence 
grCreateGraphicsPipeline 
grCreateImage 
grCreateImageView 
grCreateMsaaState 
grCreateQueryPool 
grCreateQueueSemaphore 
grCreateRasterState 
grCreateSampler 
grCreateShader 
grCreateViewportState 
grDbgRegisterMsgCallback 
grDbgSetDeviceOption 
grDbgSetGlobalOption 
grDbgSetMessageFilter 
grDbgSetObjectTag 
grDbgSetValidationLevel 
grDbgUnregisterMsgCallback 
grDestroyDevice 
grDestroyObject 
grDeviceWaitIdle 
grEndCommandBuffer 
grEndDescriptorSetUpdate 
grFreeMemory 
grGetDeviceQueue 
grGetEventStatus 
grGetExtensionSupport 
grGetFenceStatus 
grGetFormatInfo 
grGetGpuInfo 
grGetImageSubresourceInfo 
grGetMemoryHeapCount 
grGetMemoryHeapInfo 
grGetMultiGpuCompatibility 
grGetObjectInfo 
grGetQueryPoolResults 
grInitAndEnumerateGpus 
grLoadPipeline 
grMapMemory 
grOpenPeerImage 
grOpenPeerMemory 
grOpenSharedMemory 
grOpenSharedQueueSemaphore 
grPinSystemMemory 
grQueueSetGlobalMemReferences 
grQueueSubmit 
grQueueWaitIdle 
grRemapVirtualMemoryPages 
grResetCommandBuffer 
grResetEvent 
grSetEvent 
grSetMemoryPriority 
grSignalQueueSemaphore 
grStorePipeline 
grUnmapMemory 
grWaitForFences 
grWaitQueueSemaphore 
grWsiWinCreatePresentableImage 
grWsiWinGetDisplayModeList 
grWsiWinGetDisplays 
grWsiWinGetScanLine 
grWsiWinQueuePresent 
grWsiWinReleaseFullscreenOwnership 
grWsiWinSetGammaRamp 
grWsiWinSetMaxQueuedFrames 
grWsiWinTakeFullscreenOwnership 
grWsiWinWaitForVerticalBlank 

******** mantleaxl64.dll ******** 
DllMain 
grAddPerfExperimentCounter 
grAddPerfExperimentTrace 
grCmdBeginPerfExperiment 
grCmdBindBorderColorPalette 
grCmdCopyOcclusionData 
grCmdElse 
grCmdEndIf 
grCmdEndPerfExperiment 
grCmdEndWhile 
grCmdIf 
grCmdInsertTraceMarker 
grCmdResetMemoryPredication 
grCmdResetOcclusionPredication 
grCmdSetMemoryPredication 
grCmdSetOcclusionPredication 
grCmdWhile 
grCreateAdvancedMsaaState 
grCreateBorderColorPalette 
grCreateFmaskImageView 
grCreatePerfExperiment 
grFinalizePerfExperiment 
grGetExtensionLibraryVersion 
grQueueDelay 
grUpdateBorderColorPalette
```

Some assumptions:
To initialize Mantle grCreateDevice needs to be called. When using the render pipeline also grCreateGraphicsPipeline needs to be called. When shutting down the application the device needs to be destroyed via grDestroyDevice. The graphics pipeline object needs to be destroyed via grDestroyObject.